# A cyclic Galois extension over $ \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, number-fields

It is known that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$ does not live in a cyclic Galois extension $L$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $4$. For example, the image of complex conjugation in $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ would have to be non-trivial in $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})/\mathbb{Q})$ which then means it would have to have order $4$, but complex conjugation has order at most $2$.

But this argument no longer works over a base field without any real places such as $K = \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ where $\omega$ is a $3$rd root of unity. That leads to the question:

> Let $ K=\mathbb{Q}(\omega) $  where $ \omega $ is a primitive 3rd root of unity, then, for *all* integers $k$, can we construct a cyclic Galois extension $ L/K$ of  degree $4k$ such that $K(\sqrt{-1}) \subset L$?

Answer (score 9):

The answer is ``yes".

Note first that in the question we may without loss restrict to cyclic extension of $2$-power degree, since the odd part of the order would split off as a direct factor, hence would simply require realization of a given odd order cyclic group over $K$, which is easy and works over (e.g.) any number field $K$.

So the question is whether $K(\sqrt{-1})/K$ can be embedded into $C_{2^n}$-extensions for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. This seems to be a difficult question for arbitrary $K$, but was answered for quadratic number fields $K$ in

> W.-D. Geyer, C.U. Jensen, *Embeddability of quadratic extensions in cyclic extensions*. Forum Math. 19 (2007), 707-725.

The relevant case for the question asked here is answered in (statement and proof of) Theorem 7, Case 1. In particular, for a prime $a\equiv 3$ mod $8$, the quadratic extensions of $K:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-a})$ which are embeddable into $C_{2^n}$-extensions for all $n$ are *exactly* $K(\sqrt{-1})$, $K(\sqrt{2})$ and $K(\sqrt{-2})$.

By the way, there's a very well-known criterion for embeddability of a quadratic extension of a general field $K$ (of characteristic $\ne 2$) into $C_4$-extensions: $K(\sqrt{a})/K$ is $C_4$-embeddable if and only if $a$ is a sum of two squares in $K$. For $K=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, this is obviously the case since $-1=(1+\omega)^2+\omega^2$. There's still a similar criterion for $C_8$-embeddability, and also, $C_{16}$-embeddability of $K(\sqrt{-1})/K$ implies $C_{2^n}$-embeddability for all $n$ (Theorem 4 of the above paper). So the critical step in the problem is really going from $C_8$ to $C_{16}$.